# Xamarin Forms : Access list data when click of a Button inside listview-viewcell

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a button inside listview-viewcell. For the button, I am using clicked event. So on click of the button, I need the details of the selected list item like the first name, email etc. I tried like following:

Xaml code:

```
  <ListView x:Name="MyDirectories"
                  HasUnevenRows="True">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                                 <Button
                                        BorderRadius="25"
                                        HeightRequest="40"
                                        WidthRequest="150"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                        Font="Bold,15"
                                        Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                        BackgroundColor="#004F7E" 
                                        Clicked="MoreDetails"
                                        Text="More Details"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         </ListView>
```

Xaml.cs code:

```
       public class MyListItemEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public UserProfileTO MyItem { get; set; }
            public MyListItemEventArgs(UserProfileTO item)
            {
                this.MyItem = item;
            }
        }

       public void MoreDetails(Object sender, MyListItemEventArgs args)
        {
             var item = args.MyItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Firstname:>"+item.firstName);
            }
       }
```

When I run getting InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
Anybody, please suggest any other solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define 'didnt work', what didnt work? What have you tried to overcome it already? Please have a look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to see how to ask a good question which will most likely yield a good answer.

Comment: Your Xaml is wrong. There is a </StackLayout> without <StackLayout>

Comment: Use MVVM, bind to command and pass a command parameter.

Comment: https://techsolutions2017.blogspot.it/2017/01/listview-in-xamarin-forms-in-mvvm.html

Comment: But what do you want to do? Because list view have tapped event and when you clic on the row, list view can show what obj is in the row. And maybe you don't need to use button on each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the model class given in MyListEventArgs:

```
   public class MyListItemEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public UserProfileHBList MyItem { get; set; }
        public MyListItemEventArgs(UserProfileHBList item)
        {
            this.MyItem = item;
        }
    }

   public void MoreDetails(Object sender, MyListItemEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.MyItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Firstname:>" + item.userProfileTO.firstName);
        }
    }
```

The firstname, email etc are another json(userProfileTO) inside of the main json(UserProfileHBList). Also forget to add stacklayout, thank you Alessandro Caliaro.